# image.url returns local full path in view.py Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Image.url of ImageField returns local path in view.py. I've checked MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py but image.url (moreover, image.path and image.name) always return local full path. I can access the file with the correct url and the file saved the correct path.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested an example from scratch using `Django 1.8.3` and `Python 2.7.6`, and it worked like a charm:

```
# models.py:
from django.db import models


class ImageTest(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

# settings.py:
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

I set up admin for this model, uploaded an image, and via shell I tested the url field of this image:

```
>>> from main.models import ImageTest
>>> ImageTest.objects.all()[0].photo.url
'media/photos/zunzun_logo.png'
```

As you can see it is a relative path. I actually don't know what can be happening in your case. Perhaps if you can paste some code here I can help you a little bit more ;). Hope this can help you to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I set like "MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/username/path/'". But the real full path is incorrect. It's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.
A common reason for getting a full local path is when you use a function to change the path in the `upload_to` field. You just have to make sure that function returns a relative path, not a full path.
In my case my function would create de necessary dirs if none existed. I needed to use the full `MEDIA_ROOT` path for that, but had to make sure it returned a relative path value for `upload_to`.